# What are the differences between call_user_func_array and calls with argumet unpacking/three dots (...$array)?

Tags: php, function-call

I have found two solutinos on how to dynamically call a `$function` on an `$instance` with the `$arguments` provided as array.

Version with [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array)

```php
$result = call_user_func_array(array($instance, $function), $arguments);
```

Easier to read with three dots notation [Argument unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

```php
$result = $instance->$function)(...$arguments);
```

Now I only found pros for the second variant - according to some guy in the docs, it is even faster.

What are the differences? Are there any cons to not use the second variant over the first?

Answer (score 1):

Note that they are actually doing different things:

Argument unpacking is just that, unpacking arguments to be used by a function.

`call_user_func_array` is calling a function and providing an array to be unpacked as arguments to that function.

In your case there won't be much of a difference as your code is doing essentially the same thing, but normally you will use `call_user_func_array` ONLY when you want to call a function via it, you won't use it just to unpack arguments (unless you are using PHP lower than 5.6).

**TLDR**:
While `call_user_func_array` does argument unpacking , it is not it's main idea, it's main idea is to call a function (and feed it arguments).

Also normally you shouldn't be calling functions like this and it signals that there is something terrible wrong with the code base, unless you have a very specific case.

Comment: But I am using it to call the function in the variable `$function` from the instance in variable `$instance`? Can you elaborate further?

Comment: You are using call_user_func_array to call your function with $arguments unpacked.

$result = $instance->$function(...$argument) is using how PHP normally works and  using ... to unpack your arguments. '...' is not part of the process of calling your function in this case, it only provides it's arguments.